# Can I create a namespace outside of all my javascript and use it like this:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused about how to deal with namespaces:

In my master page that defines the layout for all pages on my site I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/theme")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/common")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/layout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/user")
```

Here's the only script inside the layout bundle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    addAjaxControls();
    addAccessControls();
    addBodyControls();
    addContentControls();
    addThemeControls();

    if (localStorage.getItem('Sidebar')) {
        var sidebar = localStorage.getItem('Sidebar');
        setSidebar(sidebar);
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('Theme')) {
        var theme = localStorage.getItem('Theme')
        setTheme(theme);
    }
});
```

I would like to keep things well defined so is it reasonable and a good idea to add something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Layout = Layout || {};
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/theme")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/common")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/layout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/user")
```

and then in my layout.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    addAjaxControls();
    addAccessControls();
    addBodyControls();
    addContentControls();
    addThemeControls();

    if (localStorage.getItem('Sidebar')) {
        var Layout.sidebar = localStorage.getItem('Sidebar');
        setSidebar(Layout.sidebar);
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('Theme')) {
        var Layout.theme = localStorage.getItem('Theme')
        setTheme(Layout.theme);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't work :

```
var Layout.sidebar = localStorage.getItem('Sidebar');
```

Simply do

```
Layout.sidebar = localStorage.getItem('Sidebar');
```

This will add the `sidebar` property to the `Layout` object you created before.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with one good tip that will save me time. Do you think my approach to namespace is the correct way to go? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Yes. You could be a little more precise : `myModule={}; myModule.Layout = {}`. But it really depends on your application.